# How can i make this rtl - flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu6eu.png)

I have to try Textdirection, but they only show text left to right. But I want to like these images.

Thanks

Comment: Add your code snippet

Comment: Is what you want reversed text? if so take a look at the [transform](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) widget